# JavaScript how to filter two arrays at the same time

Tags: javascript

Say I have two arrays:

```
var one = [1,2,3,4,5];

var two = ["A","B","C","D","E"];
```

If i were to filter the first array so that it returns this result:

```
 var resultOne = one.filter(v => v == 2 || v == 3 );
```

The result would return `[2,3]` but how would I filter the other array to return `[B,C]`... based on the result of this first one ?

Comment: Is it depending on Index?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what im looking for here

Comment: Will the two arrays always be the same length?

Comment: Yes they will be the same

Comment: What about just using `two.splice(1,2)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement filter on the array by passing the index, return if `index + 1` includes in the resulted array.

**Please Note:** Since the solution is based on the index, it will not work for the random numbers of array (not sequential).

```js
var one = [1,2,3,4,5];

var two = ["A","B","C","D","E"];

var resultOne = one.filter(v => v == 2 || v == 3 );
var resultTwo = two.filter((v,i) => resultOne.includes(i+1));
console.log(resultOne);
console.log(resultTwo);
```

**OR:** In Single line:

```js
var one = [1,2,3,4,5];

var two = ["A","B","C","D","E"];

var result = two.filter((v,i) => one.filter(v => v == 2 || v == 3).includes(i+1));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for. I have to wait a few minutes to accept the answer first

Comment: Just a warning for people: This works in this very specific case, but it's not a global solution for people trying to do this with other arrays or types.

Comment: @ShaneOG97 Could you edit the question to clarify what you were trying to do here? It is ambiguous whether what you want is the values from two at the positions corresponding to the position of the matching values in one or whatever you want the values from two at the indexes indicated by the value found in one (which were the same values you were searching by in the predicate). In my answer I assumed the former but this accepted answer assumes the latter. Either way it would be good to clarify.

Answer (score 4):

```js
var one = [1,2,3,4,5];

var two = ["A","B","C","D","E"];

var resultOne = two.filter((v,i) => one[i] == 2 || one[i] == 3 );

console.log(resultOne)
```

Comment: Not what op is asking but can see how question can be misinterpreted

Comment: I'm glad you misinterpreted - your answer is what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

A good old for loop or use the second parameter of the filter callback which gives you the current array index. Simply push the corresponding element of `two` onto `resultTwo` by index.

```
var resultTwo = [];
var resultOne = one.filter((v, i) => { 
  var isMatch = v == 2 || v == 3;
  if (isMatch) resultTwo.push(two[i]);
  return isMatch;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
var one = [1,2,3,4,5];

var two = ["A","B","C","D","E"];

const [resultOne, resultTwo] = one.reduce((acc, v, i) => (v == 2 || v == 3) ? (acc[0].push(v), acc[1].push(two[i]), acc) : acc, [[], []]); 
 
 console.log(resultOne);
 console.log(resultTwo);
```

Or use this version if the two arrays haven't the same length:

```js
var one = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

var two = ["A","B","C","D","E"];

const [resultOne, resultTwo] = one.reduce((acc, v, i) => (v == 2 || v == 6) ? (acc[0].push(v), (i in two) ? acc[1].push(two[i]) : '', acc) : acc, [[], []]); 
 
 console.log(resultOne);
 console.log(resultTwo);
```

Answer (score 0):

***EDIT: Just realized somone posted the same answer... The only thing I can add is that you need to subtract 1 from your original array to arrive at the correct index.***

If you use map you can map the results from your filtering. This is assuming the result will always be an index for your second collection.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

```
var one = [1,2,3,4,5];
var two = ["A","B","C","D","E"];
var resultOne = one.filter(v => v == 2 || v == 3 );
var resultTwo = resultOne.map((indexFromResultOne) => two[indexFromResultOne - 1]); 
// Because you aren't using a zero based index.
console.log(resultTwo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the most efficient, but this is the most general and readable way I can think of to filter multiple corresponding arrays:

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var b = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];

var indices = [];

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  var v = a[i];
  
  if (v == 2 || v == 3) {
    indices.push(i);
  }
}

console.log(indices.map(i => a[i]));
console.log(indices.map(i => b[i]));
```